# iTunes "Recently Added"

Tags: itunes

Is there any way of customizing the "Recently Added" view of the iTunes Library? I would like to be able to specify a time range, as it used to be possible prior to iTunes 12.4.x. I'm thinking of some kind of hidden plist setting.

[image]

I know one can create smart playlists with a "Date Added" field, but that's not what I'm looking for: when choosing "View as Albums", there's no "Sort by date added option", which is what I'd need to replicate the recently added view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the default *Recently Added* criteria.

As you already discovered, you can make a *Smart Playlist* with a limited set of criteria, included **Date Added**.  However, iTunes doesn't allow a sort by **Date Added** when viewing as albums, unfortunately.